# What does this Binary search tree function do?

Tags: function, data-structures, output, binary-search-tree

I was wondering what does this function do and what could be the possible output of this code?

```
void TreeType::Function()
{ 
Queue<TreeNode*> q;
TreeNode* node;
if (root!= NULL) {
q.Enqueue(root);

do {
    q.Dequeue(node);
    cout << node->info << endl;

    if (node->left) 
   { q.Enqueue(node->left); }

    if (node->right) 
   { q.Enqueue(node->right); }

while (!q.IsEmpty()); }
```

Comment: Have you executed it?

Comment: Yes but I didn't understand

Comment: This prints the nodes of the tree level by level.

Answer (score 0):

this function is like level order traversal of any tree.
while there are many ending semi colons missing.